# Cannot exclude repetitions in rows in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, partition

Pipedrive_org_id is one but it has several office_id. So I need to collect necessary information by pip_org_id, not office_id. The highlight is that in tables we have info about listings and countries, where these listings are posted, only collected by office_id. After joining etc. I have repetitions among pip_org_id. I need to have one unique pip_org_id, sum of listings and country_code of frequent listings.

The mistake is: Unrecognized name: r at

Code is below:

```
select distinct cast(o.pipedrive_organization_id as int64) as pipedrive_organization_id, sum(active_listings) as active_listings, 
li.type as category, li.country_code,
row_number() over (partition by cast(o.pipedrive_organization_id as int64)
order by sum(active_listings) desc) as r
from `jamesedition-152413.data_marts.pg_offices` o
left join (
          select office_id, type, country_code, count(listing_id) as active_listings,
          row_number() over (partition by office_id
          order by count (listing_id) desc) as rank
          from `jamesedition-152413.data_marts.pg_listings`
          where available_for_jamesedition = true and active = true
          group by office_id, type, country_code
          order by office_id
          ) li
on o.office_id = li.office_id and rank = 1 and li.office_id is not null
where active_listings>0 and cast(o.pipedrive_organization_id as int64) is not null and r = 1
group by 1,3,4,5
order by pipedrive_organization_id desc
```

The code gives me the following result:

```
pipedrive_organization_id|  active_listings |category   | country_code  
59326                    |  10              |Real_Estate| IT   
59326                    |  2               |Real_Estate| FR
```

I want to have:

```
pipedrive_organization_id|  active_listings |category   |country_code   
59326                    |  12              |Real_Estate| IT
```

Comment: Your question does not make sense to anyone not familiar with your data model.  Sample data and desired results would probably help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have added the result and desired result